# convert real numbers into time object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

My data looks like this

```
 date       sym Hour Minute Second Open High  Low Close Volume
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    8     59     12 3838 3838 3838  3838    106
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    9      0     11 3838 3843 3835  3842   1616
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    9      1      0 3842 3842 3836  3837   1528
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    9      2      1 3838 3838 3836  3837    630
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    9      3      0 3837 3838 3837  3837    742
 2010/6/1 DLaMI    9      4      1 3837 3837 3835  3835   1106
```

As we can see, the first, third, forth and fifth columns represent date and time, how I can convert these into date-time object, **in particular, excluding seconds** ?
for reproducible purpose, I have put the following code：

```
date<-rep("2010/6/01",5)
hour<-rep(9,5)
minutes<-c(0:4)
data<-data.frame(date,hour,minutes)  
      date        hour minutes
 [1,] "2010/6/01" "9"  "0"    
 [2,] "2010/6/01" "9"  "1"    
 [3,] "2010/6/01" "9"  "2"    
 [4,] "2010/6/01" "9"  "3"    
 [5,] "2010/6/01" "9"  "4"
```

how I can convert these into date-time object, **in particular, excluding seconds** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to paste together (concatenate) all the time strings you're interested in:

```
x$datetime<-paste(x$date,x$Hour,x$Minute,sep=":")
```

Then, you can convert them to a time object:

```
x$new_datetime<-as.Date(x$datetime,"%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")
```

**=========== EDIT TO ADD ==========**

If you wanted it with the sample data you assembled later:

```
date<-rep("2010/6/01",5)
hour<-rep(9,5)
minutes<-c(0:4)
data<-data.frame(date,hour,minutes)
data$datetime<-paste(data$date,data$hour,data$minutes,sep=":")
data$new_datetime<-as.Date(data$datetime,"%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")
```

It doesn't produce any `NA`s

Comment: Thanks, @PavoDive , but it gives me all NAs after the second line.

Comment: I worked with you toy dataset, not with the dataframe you assembled in the lower part of your post. The `NA`s are likey coming from the variables being `hour` and not `Hour` as I have them in my call

Comment: thanks for your answer, it has been solved, marked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With your reproducible code:

```
date<-rep("2010/6/01",5)
hour<-rep(9,5)
minutes<-c(0:4)

datetime <- paste(date, hour, minutes, sep = ":")

new_datetime <- strptime(datetime, format = "%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")
```

Here is what you get:

```
> new_datetime
[1] "2010-06-01 09:00:00 CEST" "2010-06-01 09:01:00 CEST" "2010-06-01 09:02:00 CEST"
[4] "2010-06-01 09:03:00 CEST" "2010-06-01 09:04:00 CEST"
```